# How to reverse all users transactions to get the balance from previous date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to reverse all transactions done by user's to show how their balance was on a particular date
if they had done any transaction The query should get the amount tendered and add it to the user for each day.

```
Users Table
current
+---------------------------------------+
| user_id |  name   | account_balance  |
+------+--------+------------------+
|     1    |  Wells  |    1.00          |
|     2    |  John   |    10.00         |
|     3    |  Sahar  |    -5.00         |
|     4    |  Peter  |    1.00          |
+-----+--------+------------------+

Transactions table
+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|     trans_id        |   user_id   |   amount_tendered    |   trans_date       |
+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|          1          |      1      |         2.00         |   2020-12-14       |
|          2          |      2      |         4.00         |   2020-12-14       |
|          3          |      3      |         5.00         |   2020-12-15       |
|          4          |      4      |         6.00         |   2020-12-15       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Next, I need to get how the balance was as of this data 2020-12-13
Expected result.

```
as of 2020-12-13
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id       |  total_spent       | account_balance  |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|     1         |   2.00             |    3.00          |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|     2         |   4.00             |    14.00         |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|     3         |   5.00             |     0.00         |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|     4         |   6.00             |    7.00          |
+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should make it a bit more complex. Let one user have two transactions, and another user no transaction at all.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your sample data is inconsistent. `account_balance` in `users` table must match the `sum(amount_tendered)` of related rows from `transactions`. Because initial balance is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the total spent per user after the given date in a subquery, then join that with the users table and do the math:

```
select u.user_id, t.total_spent, 
    u.account_balance + coalesce(t.total_spent, 0) as account_balance
from users u
left join (
    select user_id, sum(amount_tendered) as total_spent
    from transactions
    where trans_date >= '2020-12-13'
    group by user_id
) t on t.user_id = u.user_id
```